# Detect sending (or not) of Outlook mail sent by Python (with win32com)

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

My overall goal is to send some generated emails via Outlook from Python/win32com (*unfortunately this part isn't really feasible to change*) and the method here works very well:

[How do I generate and open an Outlook email with Python (but do not send)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20956424/how-do-i-generate-and-open-an-outlook-email-with-python-but-do-not-send)

I'm using it to generate the emails, with them showing up via the Outlook UI and then I either send them (possibly with editing) or cancel them (ie do not send).

However there is one limitation and from Googling and tinkering in Python I cannot see what I should do.

**I would like to be able to programmatically log whether the displayed email was actually sent or cancelled.**

I cannot see any value returned from `mail.Display(True)` and the mail object itself doesn't show any attributes that look like they indicate what happened.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

MailItem object will fire the MailItem.Send event when it is sent.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I'm not familiar with how that works - any more details you could add to the answer?

Comment: Okay. Should probably have been a comment rather than an answer then (but thanks all the same!)

Comment: It is an answer - the event will be raised. **How** you catch it in Python, is a different question.

Comment: I suspect we'll disagree here, but it sounds to me more like a statement that without further information doesn't actually fully answer the question at hand.

Comment: I can certainly help you with the Outlook questions, but I know next to nothing about Python. I answered your Outlook question. Now it is your turn to post a Python specific question like "How do I catch COM events in Python"? That would not be Outlook specific.

Comment: There are two parts to the question, you've answered one (notification of send), the other is notification of cancel. I believe the latter means detecting move to Deleted, not sure. Events are supposed to work in Python COM.

Comment: There is no event when a message displayed by Outlook is dismissed because absolutely nothing happens in that case. It is not moved anywhere - if it was already saved, it stays in its parent folder.