# Python: Create mail - display mail but not send it - smtplib + MIMEmultipart + Outlook

Tags: python, email, display, smtplib

I am currently trying to write a function which will create a mail and then  displayed it through Outlook. 
    Like this the user will be able to create and see his new mail under Outlook, and just decide to click on **Send** or not.

I struggle to find an attribute to smtplib, or an attribute to Mimemultipart like  **smtplib.display**() or

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative') 
msg = email.message.Message() 
msg.display(True).
```

I already succesfully create and send automatically mail with smtplib. What I can't find on the web, is this attribute to display the crated mail.....

What I have:

```
def createEmailConfirmation():

    email_content  = """\
        <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
        </head>
            <body>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered m-b-0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th> Title </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td> Confirmation </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
        """     

    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg = email.message.Message()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Confirmation Mail'

    toaddr = ['useraddressmail@test.com']
    bcc = ['']
    cc = ['']

    fromaddr = ''other_useraddressmail@test.com'

    toaddrs = toaddr + cc + bcc
    password = "password"
    msg.add_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    msg.set_payload(email_content)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('**.***.**.**')
    s.set_debuglevel(False) # show communication with the server
    msg.display
```

I think it something really easy, that will only fit In one line but I can't find it...

Best Regards,

Comment: hey, check https://stackoverflow.com/q/20956424/8150371

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for your reply, I saw this post, but it's using the library "import win32com.client as win32 ", and I don't have it. I would prefer to stay with SMTP or MIMEmultipart if possible. But I don't know if it exists..

Comment: check this answer to install win32com `https://stackoverflow.com/q/23864234/8150371`.