# How to generate (not send) an outlook email with SMTP in Python

Tags: python, smtp

I am able to send emails using SMTP But was wondering if I could just generate them and have the email window pop up to review before I send it manually in outlook with SMTP

I have already been able to send emails using SMTP, now want to be able to generate the email and not send as if it’s queued up to send.

Comment: Welcome! Does this question with answers solves your problem: [How do I generate and open an Outlook email with Python (but do not send)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20956424/21350362)?